# haskell language concatenation

Tags: list, haskell, string-concatenation

this is my assignment the string concatenation function is below and below that is the function that i need help with.

```
type Language = [String]
strcat :: String -> String -> String
strcat [] y     = y
strcat (x:xs) y = x:(strcat xs y)

concat_lang :: Language -> Language -> Language
concat_lang [] y = y
concat_lang x [] = x
concat_lang (x:xs) (y:ys) = (strcat x y):(concat_lang (x:xs) ys)
```

This is my input to concat_lang : concat_lang ["a","b","c"] ["d","e","f"]

i want the output to be [ad,ae,af,bd,be,bf,cd,ce,cf]

Pls help!!

Comment: Hint: Use list comprehension and (`++` or `concat`).

Comment: You nearly got it. Your `strcat` is correct, but you have a problem in `concat_lang` - it never moves on to the next character in `xs`. Do you need more hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension makes life much easier

```
lang xs ys = [x:y:[] | x <- xs , y <- ys]
```

`lang` is polymorphic, if this is undesirable, simply add a type signature.

Answer (score 0):

```
combinations :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
combinations xs ys = concatMap (flip zip ys . repeat) xs


type Language = [String]

concat_lang :: Language -> Language -> Language
concat_lang xs ys = map f $ combinations xs ys
    where
        f (x,y) = x ++ y
```

use

```
concat_lang ["a","b","c"] ["d","e","f"]
```

to get

```
["ad","ae","af","bd","be","bf","cd","ce","cf"]
```

Answer (score 0):

concat_lang xs ys = [ x++y | x <- xs, y <- ys]

Answer (score 0):

Classic example where Applicative Functors can come in handy:

```
>> import Control.Applicative
>> (++) <$> ["a", "b", "c"] <*> ["d", "e", "f"]
   ["ad","ae","af","bd","be","bf","cd","ce","cf"]
>>
```

You should definitely check out Aplicative Functors for this ...